# Mechanisms of production of heat in collision

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

Consider an electron moving through a resistor, heat is constantly radiated out of that resistor due to continuous collisions of electrons inside.
How is this heat produced??
Also, can we generally explain the production of electromagnetic radiation (heat) in case of other inelastic collisions as well.

Comment: Heat is generated because of transfer of energy between electrons and atoms. This gain in energy by the atoms is heat. And note that not not all heat is transferred out as em waves

Comment: Yes, I understand why it is generated, my problem is with understanding of how it is generated!

Comment: @FellowTraveller Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Atoms don't gain heat. They gain microscopic internal kinetic and potential energy.

Comment: Further, I do agree that not all the heat is transferred as electromagnetic waves, but please let me know what is the case specifically here.

Comment: You mean to know the mechanism of heat generation due to collision?

Comment: @fellow Traveller, yes

Comment: @BobD, yes I agree that heat is a macroscopic quantity. My initial statement must read “this gain in energy in atoms **is seen as** heat macroscopically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal energy and temperature of the resistor increases due to the work done by the lattice structure during the collisions in taking kinetic energy away from the electrons. Then the elevation of the temperature of the resistor relative to the surroundings results in heat transfer from the resistor to the surroundings by a combination of conduction, convection, and radiation.

You can think of it roughly in terms of friction work. Vigorously rub your hands together. When you do so you are doing friction work which raises the temperature of the surface of your skin, making your hands feel warm.

> Thanks for answering, can you further explain how work done leads to
>   increase in temperature, with the example of rubbing hands, we have
>   more of same problem but not a reasoning for it.

Temperature is a measure of kinetic energy at the microscopic level. When the electrons collide with the lattice structure of the resistor, the electrons lose kinetic energy and the lattice structure gains kinetic energy in terms of translation, rotation and/or vibration. This shows up as an increase in temperature of the resistor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you further explain how work done leads to increase in temperature, with the example of rubbing hands, we have more of same problem but not a reasoning for it.

Comment: @YashkalpSharma See my update.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Bob D

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism can be seen by the following cartoons. First consider a lattice (we will stick to 1D but the same can be readily extended to higher dimensions). [image]
These are neutral atoms. However in the presence of an electron, if the atoms are polarisable, then there will be separation of negative and positive clouds. [image]
But now the electron will feel repulsive force due to the negative cloud and will hop to the next spot. The direction of hop depends on the applied electric field. [image]
But when the electron hops to the next site the atom that was earlier to the right is now to the left. Thus has to swap the polarity. This causes the atom that was to the left in the previous site to oscillate its polarity. This is a way in which the electron’s energy is transferred as atom’s kinetic energy.

Now consider the case where the atoms are vibrating about their mean (they have kinetic energy at finite temperature). Thus the electron that is hopping from one place to another will have to in some sense move in synchronous with the atomic vibrations. And of course when the electron is moving it locally changes the vibrations by the mechanism pointed out earlier. This is the reason for resistance and for the increase in heat of the system.